# how to get histogram from additional "count" column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with two columns trying to do histogram in excel.

First column is the `value`, second column is the `count` of the `value`. For example

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | 1 |
| 45 | 3 |
| 50 | 5 |
| ... | ... |
| 20 | 1 |

I can get histogram using the first `value` column with no issue, just following some [tutorials](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-histogram-85680173-064b-4024-b39d-80f17ff2f4e8). In this way, each `value` is considered to be hit **once**.

How to generate a histogram using Excel taking both `value` and `count` column into account?

Comment: It's simple, select both columns the go to INSERT and select Clustered Column BAR graph ,, then select any BAR ,, right click then Format Data Series,, now set Series Overlap & Gap Width 0%,, hit Ok ,, you get Histogram (which is basically Bar Graph but no GAP between Bars),,, hope this help you, remember standard HISTOGRAM command can't do this (2 Columns) !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Pivot table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) in Excel.

Select "value" and "count"

In the lower right corner, drag "value" to rows, set "count" to values.

Then right click on the data, "group" the data.